# not able to install groovy using sdkman in docker image

Tags: docker, groovy, sdk

I use a script to build thee dockerfile. below is my script...

```
echo "FROM ubuntu:14.04" >> Dockerfile
echo "RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh" >> Dockerfile
echo "RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y" >> Dockerfile
echo "RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common" >> Dockerfile
echo "RUN apt-get -y update && add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java" >> Dockerfile 
echo "RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections" >> Dockerfile
echo "RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set-selections" >> Dockerfile 
echo "RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer" >> Dockerfile
echo "RUN apt-get install -y curl " >> Dockerfile
echo "RUN apt-get install -y unzip " >> Dockerfile
echo "RUN apt-get -y update && curl -s get.sdkman.io | bash" >> Dockerfile
echo 'RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"' >> Dockerfile
echo 'RUN source ~/.profile' >> Dockerfile
echo "RUN yes | sdk install groovy" >> Dockerfile
...
docker build -t imagename:version ./
...
```

> but I get the below error

```
RUN yes | sdk install groovy
 ---> Running in 09056add5ab7
/bin/sh: sdk: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c yes | sdk install groovy' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

> if I dont use this command "sdk install groovy" the build is sucessfull. and then i an run the image and issue the same command and it works.

Any help, any idea why this is hapenning?

Comment: what do you mean with: and issue the same command and it works.

Comment: You can install groovy in a more easy way on ubuntu 14.04: just add in your dockerfile after an update: `apt-get -y install groovy`. After that I can go inside my container and check `root@4ab59267d4f6:/# groovy -version
Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.7.0_121 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux`. It's not a real answer because you want to use sdkman but it can maybe help a bit.

Comment: @lorenzvth7 that's fine if you want groovy 1.8.6 which is years old

Comment: Than he can better take a look to this as base image https://github.com/donbeave/docker-sdkman/blob/master/Dockerfile or use the same entry-point approach

Comment: I think `sdk` is a shell function, not a binary on the path. Have you tried `RUN yes | /bin/bash -l -c sdk install groovy` ?

Comment: @lorenzvth7 I need  groovy 2.47

Comment: @Poundex .. thanks  a lot RUN yes | /bin/bash -l -c 'sdk install groovy' worked :)

Comment: I am using entrypoint for other commands which will fire up an application inside it

Answer (score 3):

```
RUN yes | /bin/bash -l -c 'sdk install groovy'
```

worked.